# Bitwise expression in System Verilog causing Icarus Verilog to Hang

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have ripple carry adder in system verilog as shown below. The circuit isn't functionally correct which is not my problem here. My problem is this line  `c_in[0] =~(c_in[63]) | carry_in ;` cause my simulator (Icarus Verilog) to hang. When I change the operator `|` to `^` it simulates without hanging. I want to find out what is causing the simulator to hang.

```
`include "adder.sv" 
module ripple_adder #(parameter width = 64)(input [width-1:0] a, b, input carry_in, output logic carry_out, output [width-1:0] sum);
logic [width:0] c_in; 
 genvar i; 
always @(*) begin
 c_in[0] =~(c_in[63]) | carry_in ;
 carry_out =~(c_in[64]) | carry_in | ~(c_in[19]);
 end
generate 
 for(i=0; i<width; i=i+1) begin 
  adder dut(a[i], b[i], c_in[i],c_in[i+1],sum[i]);
 end 
 endgenerate 
endmodule
```

**1 bit adder**

```
module adder(input logic a, b, carry_in, output logic carry_out, sum); 
 always @(a, b, carry_in) begin 
   sum = a ^ b ^ carry_in;
   carry_out = a&b | (a^b) & carry_in;
 end 
 endmodule
```

**Testbench**

````
`include "ripple_adder.sv"

module tb_adder;
    parameter width = 64;
    logic [width-1:0] a, b;
    logic carry_in;
    logic [width-1:0] sum;
    logic carry_out;
    logic [width:0] sum_out;
    int passedFile;

    ripple_adder #(.width(width)) dut(.a(a), .b(b), .carry_in(carry_in), .carry_out(carry_out), .sum(sum));

    initial begin
        passedFile = $fopen("passed.txt", "w");
        assertCornerCases();
        test();
        $fclose(passedFile);
    end
    task test;
    integer i;
        for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) begin
            a = {$urandom(),$urandom()}; b = {$urandom(),$urandom()}; carry_in = 0; s_out = a + b + carry_in;
        #5 if (sum == s_out[width-1:0]) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1); else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
           if (carry_out == s_out[width]) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1); else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
        end

        for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) begin
            a = {$urandom(),$urandom()}; b = {$urandom(),$urandom()}; carry_in = 1; s_out = a + b + carry_in;
        #5 if (sum == s_out[width-1:0]) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1); else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
           if (carry_out == s_out[width]) $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 1); else $fdisplay(passedFile, "%d", 0);
        end
    endtask : assertOutput

endmodule : tb_adder
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplify and with `a` and `b` as 4-bit values so `c_in[0]` would be `~(c_in[3]) | carry_in`.

Assume `a=4`, `b=3`, and `carry_in=0`. The sum would be 7 and `c_in[3]` would be 0 (initially). `c_in[0]` would become 1 per your equations; making the the sum 8 with `c_in[3]` as one. That means `c_in[0]` will be re-evaluated back to 0. Hence the feedback loop that prevents the simulator from moving the the next time step.
Since you are running with 64-bit values, the hang has a smaller change of being observed until it picks a condition where `a+b == (1<<(width-1))-1` and `carry_in == 1'b0`

Your `c_in[0]` and `carry_out` assignments look very odd for a ripple adder. They can be greatly simplified.